# Ajax won't post if textarea input is to large

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, textarea

I have:

```
    @Html.TextArea("CountersInput", "", 5, 10, null)
    <button onclick="updateCounters()">Update list</button>

<script>
        function updateCounters() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/ExportModels/CounterList",
                type: "GET",
                data: { counters: $("textarea#CountersInput").val() }
            }).done(function (result) {
                $('#AddCounters').val(result);
            });
        }
    </script>
```

It all works well until the input for the textarea becomes to big and the controller method is no longer called.
What is the cause of this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

GET method has a restriction on a query string length (~2000 chars, AFAIR). Change `type` from `GET` to `POST`.

Comment: but can I get data from server if it's of type post?

Comment: Unless your action method has a `[HttpGet]` attribute, there will be no problem. ASP.NET MVC is smart enough to check both query string and POST parameters.